# How to overlap the ROI into the original scan image in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing, roi

I have two medical images. One is the "scan image" and the other is the "region of interest" (ROI) of that scan image. Now I need to overlay on top of the other. Here is the original scan image. 
[image]

```
Scan image
```

[image]

```
ROI image
```

How can I overlay, such that I should be able to see the ROI region in the original scan image?.
I would like to do this in python.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem like below. If anyone is interested in it, you can do as follow;

```
from PIL import Image

import numpy as np

img = Image.open("path/to/the/roi")

background = Image.open("path/to/the/scan/image")

background.paste(img, (0, 0), img)
background.save('path/to/save',"PNG")
```

The result looks like below as I wanted.
[image]

ref: [click for reference](https://www.science-emergence.com/Articles/How-to-overlay--superimpose-two-images-using-python-and-pillow-/)